# How to view the log of my crashed app?

Tags: android-studio

My problem is quite a troublesome one, i made an app on Android Studio that has a TextView that displays the Firebase registration token upon launch (I'm still new to Firebase and Android Studio, i'm experimenting), i've been building APK files of my app to test it on my phone since Android Studio doesn't detect my phone when it's hooked to my laptop for some reason and i can't use emulation because my laptop is old (i think it doesn't support virtualization), so whenever i try to launch my app on my phone i get the equivalent of MyApp stopped working in French and i don't know where to access the log files to see what the error is so i can't fix it, so any solutions?

Comment: Use `adb logcat | find /i "your_string"` or `adb logcat | grep -i "your_string"`.

Comment: Where do i use this?

Comment: Learn from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat